# post callback doesn't run

Tags: jquery, xml

There is a strange error in my jQuery script. If I comment alert("wait"); the second alert doesn't show, although with this line it shows up.

/char/lol returns an xml with data.

```
  $("#chat_form").submit(function(){
    alert("wait"); // without this alert the second alert doesn't
    $.post("/chat/lol", 
           { user: $("#f_user").val(), 
             msg: $("#f_msg").val()
           }, 
           function(data){
                 alert("Im in");
           }, 
           'xml');
    });
```

Edit:
This way it also works. IMPORTANT: "done" appears first, after that appears "Im in". It seems like 'submit' exits before 'post' finishes and than it kills 'post'.

```
$.post("/chat/lol", {user: $("#f_user").val(), msg: $("#f_msg").val()}, function(data){
    // pobranie nowych wiadomości z serwera
      alert("Im in");
    }, 'xml');
    alert("done");
```

What am I doing
 wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code with that alert commented out?

Comment: //alert("wait"); // without this alert the second alert doesn't - the only difference

Comment: What does Firebug/console/etc. say is happening?

Comment: What triggers this piece of code?  Verify that you are sending the correct data.

Comment: Chrome debugger doesn't say anything like it worked ok. Anyway like I said - with the first alert it works so data should be correct.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: You can't comment out a line of code by yourself?!

Comment: This code is triggered by clicking a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#chat_form").submit(function(){
    data = $("#chat_form").serialize();
    $.post("/chat/lol", data, 
           function(response){
                 alert("Im in");
           }, 'xml');
    });
    return false;
}
```

i.e. I suspect you didn't have return false (or preventDefault) that could be one of the reasons your ajax submit worked not exactly you want it to.